# Meaning of degree of finite morphsim of curves and Relation with degree of divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a nonsingular curve, $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^r$ be an embedding determined by the linear system $|L|$ and let $X'$ be the image of $X$. 
${\rm deg}f$ define to $[K(X):K(X)')]$ where $K(x),K(X')$ are function fields respectively

I saw two fact :

1.${\rm deg}f$ is the length of $f^{-1}(q)$ for closed point $q$.

2.${\rm deg}L = {\rm deg}f {\rm deg}X'$

But I can't understand it. Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The degree of $f$ is the number of points in a typical fibre of $f$.
If $p$ is a closed point of $X'$, then it is also the degree of the divisor
$f^{-1}(p)$.  (Typically, this will consist of distinct points each with multiplicity one.)

The degree of $L$ is the number of zeroes of a generic section.  A generic section
of $L$ corresponds to a generic hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb P^r$.  Thus the number
of zeroes of the section will be the number of points in $X$ whose images in $X'$ lies in $H$.  Now the number of points in $X' \cap H$ equals deg $X'$ (this is the definition of the degree of a curve), and there are deg $f$ points of $X$ lying over each of these, so altogether there are deg $f \cdot \deg H$ points
of $X$ lying over $X' \cap H$.  This proves your second fact.